# How to use TextToSpeech: stopping and playing again?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have some problem with TTS. I'm using code like below, but when tts "is speaking", calling `tts.speak()` after `tts.stop()` doesn't work (no voice). Both return `0` (`SUCCESS`). What can be wrong with that ? Is better approach for that ?

```
 if(tts.isSpeaking()) {
     tts.stop(); // return SUCCESS
 }
 tts.speak(longText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null); // return SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish but if you want to just ignore what speaking, you can just use QUEUE_FLUSH without stop().

```
//if(tts.isSpeaking()) {
//   tts.stop();
//}
tts.speak(longText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Comment: it stop the next message that i need to play simultaneously